# Circle not centered - expected something else

Tags: swiftui

i have this code. The circle is not centered. I assume because of the edgesIgnoring...and yes, if i comment it out, it is centered. But if i comment out the "scaledToFill" it is centered too, although the edgesIgnoring is in...is this a bug or am i misunderstanding something? I tested on an iPhoneX Preview...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
            Circle()
                .scaledToFill()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes, it's a bug. The circle's size is being calculated *including the safe area*, but the circle's horizontal offset is being calculated to center it assuming the size it would have *not including the safe area*. Both circles have their left edge at approximately -204 pixels on an iPhone 11, which leaves the larger one uncentered.

Answer (score 2):

I try to propose solution (one might say it is workaround - does not matter), for some cases it might be acceptable, because both centred properly, so worth posting:

*Note: order of modifiers important!*

1) approach 1

[image: SwiftUI ellipse]

```
 Ellipse()
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .scaledToFill()
```

2) approach 2

[image: SwiftUI circle]

```
Circle()
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .scaledToFill()
```